# swt.graphics.ImageLoader.save() not flushed?

Tags: java, image, swt, save

I'm using this class `swt.graphics.ImageLoader` to save a file as a PNG:

```
ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
loader.data = new ImageData[] { m_imgdat };
loader.save(selected, SWT.IMAGE_PNG);
```

Yet sometimes the file I get is incomplete. the last line of pixels is black and some programs (photoshop) refuse to open it altogether.
Is there something I'm missing? How can I tell this class to flush the file and close it?

Answer (score 1):

The principle is correct, but you may try to save it like [`ImageDialog`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/directory/ldapstudio/valueeditors/image/ImageDialog.java.htm) does:

See its **[buttonPressed()](http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/directory/ldapstudio/valueeditors/image/ImageDialog.java.htm#160)** method:

```
try
{
    ImageData imageData = new ImageData( new ByteArrayInputStream JavaDoc( this.newImageRawData ) );
    if ( imageData.type != this.requiredImageType )
    {
        ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader();
        imageLoader.data = new ImageData[] { imageData };
        ByteArrayOutputStream JavaDoc baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream JavaDoc();
        imageLoader.save( baos, this.requiredImageType );
        this.newImageRawDataInRequiredFormat = baos.toByteArray();
    }
    else
    {
        this.newImageRawDataInRequiredFormat = this.newImageRawData;
    }
}
catch ( SWTException swte )
{
    this.newImageRawDataInRequiredFormat = null;
}
```

---

Note: When it [saves an image](http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/directory/ldapstudio/valueeditors/image/ImageDialog.java.htm#274), it does use the following code:

```
try
    {
    File JavaDoc file = new File JavaDoc( returnedFileName );
    FileOutputStream JavaDoc out = new FileOutputStream JavaDoc( file );
    out.write( currentImageRawData );
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```